# Create functions or inherit from paramiko class?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have to connect to several servers using ssh and execute different commands for each one in different points of the script.

This is the code for ssh connections I'm using:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect( host, key_filename=keypriv, timeout=10)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("vgdisplay -v -F | grep -v 'vg_status=deactivated'")
vgdata = stdout.readlines()
```

As I'm going to open several connections and execute several commands. I'm thinking about create a new class that inherits from paramiko and add some functions (create, close and execute) or create a new class without inherit from paramiko.

Is there any pythonist way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question you'll have to ask yourself here is "[Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)"?

This question basically boils down to asking yourself whether you have a "has a" relationship or a "is-a" relationship. In your case this is a "has a" relationship as the class you are creating is doing something **with** the paramiko connection, not **as** the connection.

I'm not entirely sure what these `create`, `execute` and `close` methods are going to do but this sounds to me like a "connection manager" or some convenience methods, for which composition would be the right choice in my opinion.